# Is autorization code is secure in oauth2?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am completely new to oauth2. I need to implement oauth2 for securing my REST services. After reading different blog posts what I under stood is,

1. There are 3 things, Client,Provider and webapp.
2. Web app Wants to access information about the user from the provider.
3. If the client allows , provider will give a authorization code to the client and webapp in query string.
4. Now the web app will use the authorization code to obtain the access token using which it can access the resources.

Now I am bit confused regarding the authorization code. Is it secure ?

What is the life span of a authorization code? If someone else will steal the authorization code will he be able to access the user resources?

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) recommends that the maximum lifetime of an authorization code be 10 minutes ([4.1.2. Authorization Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2)). In other words, an authorization code expires in 10 minutes.

An authorization code is just like a ticket which is exchanged with an access token at the token endpoint. An authorization code is not an access token, so no one can access any data with an authorization code. In addition, an OAuth 2.0 server will discard or invalidate the authorization code after the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

These two request have to be done over HTTPS (mandatory) since they are requests to the OAuth server which has to support only HTTPS. It's only the client/requestor server who do not have to support HTTPS, so only the Auth Code is potentially sent in clear over HTTP. But the Auth Code is useless without the client ID/Secret. Basically the point of the OAuth Code flow is that the burden of having an SSL-enabled server is on the OAuth Provider (Google/Facebook etc...) and not on the users of the APIs